# How to use char in C

Tags: c, char, cs50

I'm struggling to get Char to work.  It keeps returning an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main (void)

{
int tower_height;
char #;

//                          Inputs        
do {     
    printf("Let's build! Give me a number between 0 and 23 'inclusive'.\n");
    tower_height = GetInt();
}   
while 
    (tower_height < 0 || tower_height > 23); 

//                          Outputs

for (tower_height = 0; tower_height <= 23; tower_height++)
printf ("%c = tower_height - 2\n");

}
```

Comment: in "char #;" # is a reserved keyword. Give a different variable name.

Comment: line printf ("%c = tower_height - 2\n"); is messed up also. You probably want to print an int (%d) and need to supply it after the string.

Comment: what are u trying to do??

Comment: Can this question be moved to the CS50 section? It might be most useful there.

Comment: Also, it is good to start your learning without using the loops first. Start with keywords in C, variable naming conventions, using semicolon and types brackets etc. Get a good handbook, and start with one at a time. All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, `#` is not a valid variable name.
You can see how `#` is properly used in the first line of your code: `#include <stdio.h>`

Instead, call your char variable something that uses letters and numbers eg: `char c;`

Comment: Thanks.  Figured this one might help other noobs as well.

Comment: Yeah - spotting/pointing out the error is one thing - providing a solution is good too :)

Answer (score 2):

C identifier names may contain letters, underscore, and digits, as long
as the first character isn't a digit, and as long as the identifier
isn't a keyword. They may not contain `#`.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is not a valid variable name.